# Rsync and ssh script

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, password

**I really dont need ssh keys. The server has good security implemented.**

I need the script to input the password without user usage/interaction.
How can I make this? Its CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

```
#!/bin/bash

#Credentials

PASS="p77Z"


sudo rsync -rlptDvz --owner=cmsseren --group=cmsseren /home/serena/public_html/ -e ssh root@ip:/home/cmsseren/public_html3/


ssh root@ip 'chown -R cmsseren:cmsseren /home/cmsseren/public_html3/*'
```

Comment: You really should be using ssh keys for this.

Comment: Yes, you really want SSH keys. Having good security on the server has no relation to the fact that using SSH keys is the solution you want to accomplish the task you've desribed in the way you describe it.

Comment: If you allow root to login via ssh with a password, then that server absolutely does not have good security implemented.

Comment: Ok, anyone answer my question,I give up.
How can I add ssh keys to automatize this?

Comment: I agree with the above comments, also, not only it's going to be more secure to use keys buy also easier that what you are trying to do, if the easiest option is also the most secure, why go with something harder and insecure? By the way, with a cleartext password stored in a script, the other security measures are useless.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to use a password. You want to set up SSH keys. This will let you use both `rsync` and `ssh` without having to enter a password. I'm not sure you'll need the `sudo` on the `rsync`, either.

The ssh keys can be generated with the `ssh-keygen` utility. Check `man 1 ssh-keygen` for more details about how to use it.

Comment: The keys can also be _distributed_ with `ssh-copy-id`.